# GWT with Visualization: link two visualizations to the same data

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I have a BarChart and Table on the same data.

I want to link these two visualizations such that if I sort the table column by a mouse click on one of the columns, it would reflect in the bar chart.

I found one example for the Visualization api:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/examples.html

But the sort method is not avaiable for com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [google-gwt-apis](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/) haven't been updated for a long time and don't support the latest gogole chart features. 
However you can extend DataTable and use [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) to implement the sorting and unsupported functions yourself.

Refer to the [DataTable](http://www.google.com/codesearch#ow6Lmd7dcZY/trunk/visualization/visualization/src/com/google/gwt/visualization/client/DataTable.java&q=DataTable%20package%3ahttp://gwt-google-apis%5C.googlecode%5C.com).java and the [google chart tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#DataTable) for more information.